# Angular.js issue with $sce preventing me from passing what I want into my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive that will animate a PNG Sequence and everything is working good when I hard code in the image url, however when I try to pass a dynamic url I get an error that $sce is not allowing it.

Here is my directive code:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope: {
            height: '@height',
            frames : '@frameCount',
            src : '@src',
            width : '@width'
        },
        link : function (scope, element) {
            var currentPosition = 0;
            var i = 1;
            var fps = 1000 / 30; // Setting this to 30 frames per second.
            element.css({
                backgroundImage : 'url(' + scope.src +')',
                height : scope.height + 'px',
                width : scope.width + 'px'
            });
            setInterval(function () {
                if(i < scope.frames) {
                    currentPosition = currentPosition + (parseInt(scope.height));
                    element.css('background-position-y', '-' + (currentPosition) + 'px');
                    i++;
                }
            }, fps);
        }
    }
```

Next in my view I add the directive:

```
<png-sequencer src='assets/images/png-sequences/{{user.segment}}_{{user.condition}}.png' frame-count='12' height='37' width='64'></png-sequencer>
```

However I get the following error:

angular.js:13236 Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: assets/images/png-sequences/{{user.segment}}_{{user.condition}}.png
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.

If I replace the src with hard coded values such as "assets/images/png-sequences/day_rainy.png" then everything works correctly. What do I need to do to allow the dynamic src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the src is a reserved word, changing that to pngSrc fixed the issue.